# Chromium not deleting Cache

Tags: http, caching, chromium, vivaldi

I think I might have misconfigured my webserver at some point to serve wrong caching policies, but now I cannot get them removed.

When I access my site, it keeps showing the old content, only CTRL+F5 does the trick. But that is only a temporary fix, after reloading normally again, it shows the old version. I've tried every method I could think of for disabling/clearing cache, but I can't seem to get it out of the browser.

After inspecting the traffic with wireshark, it seems like there isn't even a request being sent to the server (only to the index file, which isn't the one I am trying to access).

Any ideas on what could cause this, or how to potentially fix this.

I am using the newest version of Vivaldi with Chromium, but other people using different browser seem to have the same experience of old versions being served to them.

Comment: It sounds like you're not using headers on the response to indicate your desired cache policy. See [`Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) for a start.

Comment: I'm not actually sure it's a caching problem anymore, as the browser just doesn't even send a request to the server anymore (just to the index file for some reason, even though I am accessing different paths - even paths I've never been to before)